# Parse TSQL/Sybase *= conditional operator used to express outer join using ANTLR4

Tags: t-sql, antlr, sybase, antlr4, sap-ase

Sybase has that non-ANSI SQL conditional operator used to express outer join: *=.

It's being deprecated (http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbusage/apxa-transactsqlouter-joins-aspen.html).

As we are moving from Sybase ASE to MySQL I have started to use ANTLR4 to parse the Sybase SQL code to try to translate it into the MySQL code equivalent.

I have tried adding it to the TSqlParser.g4 grammar available here: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/tsql. See '*' '=' at the end of the line below but it doesn't work

```
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx
// Spaces are allowed for comparison operators.
comparison_operator
    : '=' | '>' | '<' | '<' '=' | '>' '=' | '<' '>' | '!' '=' | '!' '>' | '!' '<' | '*' '='
    ;
```

I tried a few things to make it work like escaping \* and removing the *= assignment_operator but nothing works. It's probably a dumb question since I'm new to ANTLR. :-(

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input `*=` is being tokenised as a `MULT_ASSIGN` by the lexer. You defined it as two separate tokens: `'*' '='`, which is not the same as `'*='`.

If you parse following the input with your grammar:

```sql
SELECT Q
FROM T
WHERE ID * = 42;
```

it will go fine, but to parse this properly:

```sql
SELECT Q
FROM T
WHERE ID *= 42;
```

you need to do it like this:

```
comparison_operator
    : ... | '*='
    ;
```

and to support both, do this:

```
comparison_operator
    : ... | '*' '=' | '*='
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks, Bart! That did the trick. what I don't understand is that the rest of the comparison_operators have it separated (say '>' '=') and yet when I use '>=' in my query that works: comparison_operator
    : '=' | '>' | '<' | '<' '=' | '>' '=' | '<' '>' | '!' '=' | '!' '>' | '!' '<' | '*' '='
    ;

Comment: That is because there are only tokens defined for `<` and `=` separately: there is no token `<=`. If that were the case, thing would go wrong in the same way as with `*=`